# Can drinking coconut water harm sperm production?

Tags: medical-science, human-reproduction, fruit, sperm

In a remote rural area of India while traveling, I came to know that the people there believe that

> Coconut water should not be drunk by males as it harms sperm production [count?].

Is there truth to it? I googled it and found the reverse information. In [this source](http://minnewiki.publicradio.org/index.php/Coconut_Water_Increase_Semen_Production_Large_Amounts_Sperm_Coventry,_Uk) from Minnesota public radio, it is stated that,

> Increase semen load with herbs coconut water increase semen production produce more come. Diet to increase sperm best food to make sperm increase my sperm loads. This the side effects. That your condition is claimed the liver which includes both the coconut water increase semen production park, the time leading celebs where fat.

Another source at [Cocotap](http://www.cocotap.com/nutrition.htm) claimed:

> "Coconut water is sweet, increasing semen. promoting digestion, and clearing the urinary path," says Ayurvedic medicine of India. Coconut water, also called coconut juice, is the liquid found inside a fresh coconut. Contrary to popular belief, this liquid is not the same as coconut milk.

So which one is true? Does coconut water at all has anything to deal with sperm production or count?

Answer (score 8):

The two sources that are provided for notability are largely valueless.

The first one (link now broken) appears to be computer-generated gibberish keywords [intended to attract Google to some spam links](http://www.seobythesea.com/2013/10/google-gibberish-content-to-demote-pages/) for fertility pills.

The second one makes an unsubstantiated reference to an [untrustworthy form of alternative medicine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ayurveda).

My searches through the literature failed to find any studies of the effect of coconut water in the diet. That isn't very definitive as an answer, so I will refer to:

- Jean W. H. Yong, Liya Ge, Yan Fei Ng and Swee Ngin Tan, [The Chemical Composition and Biological Properties of Coconut (Cocos nucifera L.) Water](http://www.mdpi.com/1420-3049/14/12/5144), Molecules 2009, 14, 5144-5164; doi:10.3390/molecules14125144.

In this paper, they present a breakdown of the chemical composition of coconut water. More importantly, they perform a literature review of the many apparent applications of the components of coconut water (e.g. the plant tissue culture industry, antioxidants, anti-proliferative and apoptogenic effects against human cancer cells, etc.)

The paper reads as quite biased towards these "marvellous tropical fruits" and some of the claims sound very... ambitious. I am skeptical that most of them will stand up to further analysis.

Nonetheless, despite their attempts to find all of the biochemical and biological properties of coconut water, they report nothing regarding the increase or decrease of semen or sperm production in men ingesting coconut water.

I see this as confirmation that, as of 2009, there was not strong scientific evidence about coconut water's effect on sperm, and that this is just an urban legend.